# comparing xlsx and xlsm file based on column and save the data to new xlsx

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm writing python code to get the common rows across two xls files and save the result to new xlsx file.

I could get the data from the two sheets but I got ended up with infinite loop.

```
     # loading the Headcount excel
hc_wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename='Headcount.xlsm')

# reading the worksheet required
hc_ws = hc_wb.get_sheet_by_name('Headcount')
rowmax = hc_ws.max_row
staffID = 8

# create new workbook
modified_wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
modified_ws = modified_wb.worksheets[0]
modified_ws.cell(column=1, row=1).value = "StaffID"
modified_ws.cell(column=2, row=1).value = "Name"
modified_ws.cell(column=3, row=1).value = "Department Code"
modified_ws.cell(column=4, row=1).value = "Department Name"
modified_ws.cell(column=5, row=1).value = "Finance Managed Entity Level 1"



# loading login report data excel
login_wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename='login_report.xlsx')
login_ws = login_wb.get_sheet_by_name('sheet1')
login_rowmax = login_ws.max_row

print("crossed 3rd step------------------")


# looping through the rows and add the missing '0's to the StaffID
for rown in range(2,rowmax+1):

    for login_rows in range(2, login_rowmax + 1):
        if (str(login_ws.cell(row=login_rows, column=1).value).strip().zfill(staffID)) == str(hc_ws.cell(row=rown, column=1).value).strip().zfill(staffID):
            modified_ws.cell(row=rown, column=1).value = str(hc_ws.cell(row=rown, column=1).value).strip().zfill(staffID)
            modified_ws.cell(row=rown, column=2).value = str(hc_ws.cell(row=rown, column=23).value)
            modified_ws.cell(row=rown, column=3).value = str(hc_ws.cell(row=rown, column=24).value)
            modified_ws.cell(row=rown, column=4).value = str(hc_ws.cell(row=rown, column=25).value)
            modified_ws.cell(row=rown, column=5).value = str(hc_ws.cell(row=rown, column=26).value)


modified_wb.save('ModifiedData.xlsx')
```

Comment: What part is looping? Just so we can help narrow the problem :)

Comment: @Shane, second part..... I mean its looping continuously after if condition...

Comment: Are you sure you are in an endless loop, have you try to debug/print the ranges and the indexes rown and login_rows to see if their values changes?

Comment: @Nico238, the values are changing though... but the program is running since half hour and any suggestions for optimization of the code, pls...

Comment: @Vishy you are doing rowmax * login_rowmax comparaisons, so it may be long. I don't have enough information to help you. You should search for a way to reduce the number of comparaison : e.g if you can use a set which store the ids and search through it, you'd reduce the complexity from O(n^2) to O(n log(n))...

Comment: How large are these files? Can you provide minimal examples we can work with?

Comment: one file has 237396 rows and another one has rows.

Comment: Can you make the code a bit more legible?

Comment: @Vishy to ensure you are in an endless loop there a simple way to debug is to print a counter variable in the same for loop as your if